# How to reference a range between two ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to delete the values between the following two Excel ranges:

- `ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Offset(1, 1)`
- `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Sub Total").Offset(-1, 0)`

Do I need to store the above two values in some variable or perhaps there is a better way doing this as the following won't compile:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Offset(1, 1):ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Sub Total").Offset(-1, 0)").SelectSelection.ClearContents
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare the two ranges `rangeA` and `rangeB` and assign them to the one you wanted. Then, getting their top left cell with the `.Cells(1, 1)` property, assign these to `rangeC`.

Using `ActiveSheet`  [is not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), but it will work:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim rangeA As Range
    Dim rangeB As Range
    
    Set rangeA = ActiveSheet.Range("A10").Offset(1, 1)
    Set rangeB = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("Sub Total").Offset(-1, 0)
    
    Dim rangeC As Range
    Set rangeC = ActiveSheet.Range(rangeA.Cells(1, 1), rangeB.Cells(1, 1))

    rangeC.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen - yes, this one will work as well.

Comment: @BigBen - it is a philosophic question - I would do it with `.Row` and `.Column`, if the ranges are not of one cell, but of many. This way, I will always get the top left and I will be 100% sure what is going on.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, `range.Cells(1, 1)` will work quite nicely.